# Ошибка "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта"

Tags: pascal, freepascal, pascalabc.net

```
program One;

var
  n: integer;
  a: array of array of integer;
  i,  j: integer;

begin
  read(n);
  SetLength(a, n);
  for i := 1 to n do 
    for j := 1 to n do
      read(a[i, j]);
end.
```

Почему возникает ошибка?

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы выделили память только под первое измерение, надо так же выделять под второе

```
program One;

var
  n: integer;
  a: array of array of integer;
  i,  j: integer;

begin
  read(n);

 SetLength(a, n); // выделили под количество строк

 for i := 0 to n-1 do // индексация в динамических массивах с нуля
   begin
     SetLength(a[i], n); // выделили под количество столбцов
     for j := 0 to n-1 do
       read(a[i][j]);
   end;

end.
```

Comment: Спасибо,Спасибо),Спасибо))